# While executing karate runner class I get java.lang.RuntimeException: not found: features

Tags: karate, junit5

package features;
import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;

```
public class TestRunner
{
  @Karate.Test
    Karate getAPITest()
    {
      return Karate.run("getapi").relativeTo(getClass());
    }
}
```

Feature: call API Scenario: Call Api Given url baseUrl+'/public/v1/users' And path '3668' When method Get Then status 200 * def jsonResponse = response Scenario: Call Api negative response Given url baseUrl+'/public/v1/users' And path '2769' When method Get Then status 200 * print response * def jsonResponse = response * def actName = jsonResponse.data.email * match actName == 'sinha_urmila@white.i

com.intuit.karate karate-apache 0.9.6 test   com.intuit.karate karate-junit5 1.1.0    com.intuit.karate karate-core 1.2.0.RC5

Comment: <dependency> <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId> <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId> <version>0.9.6</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId> <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId> <version>1.1.0</version> </dependency> <!-- mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intuit.karate/karate-core --> <dependency> <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId> <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId> <version>1.2.0.RC5</version> </dependency>

Comment: sorry, you are doing it wrong, especially the dependencies. maybe you should just stick to the ZIP release: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release - if you really want support, follow this process (exactly as written): https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue